# Powershell - Check if variable is in array

Tags: arrays, powershell

I created a script which return emails with specific subject and sender email addresses,

i have array of emails, and i need to compare each array member with email sender, and write output for allowed senders and if found, write output for disallowed ones

```
$sender = $result.Sender.Address - exports senders for each email
$allowed_senders = @("user1@example.com", "user2@example.com") - users who are allowed to send emails
```

I have 3 emails with following senders:

user1, user2 and user3

```
write-output "Searching for emails with subject New Empoyee.." | timestamp >> $LogFile
      Write-Verbose "Searching for emails with subject New Empoyee.."
      $searchfilter = new-object Microsoft.Exchange.WebServices.Data.SearchFilter+ContainsSubstring([Microsoft.Exchange.WebServices.Data.EmailMessageSchema]::Subject,"New Employee")
      $itemView = new-object Microsoft.Exchange.WebServices.Data.ItemView(999)
      $searchResults = $service.FindItems($Folder.ID, $searchfilter, $itemView)

      # Find destination folder

      $TargetFolderSearch = new-object Microsoft.Exchange.WebServices.Data.SearchFilter+IsEqualTo([Microsoft.Exchange.WebServices.Data.FolderSchema]::Displayname,"done") #for each folder in mailbox define search
      $TargetFolder = $MailboxRoot.FindFolders($TargetFolderSearch,$fvFolderView)
      Write-Verbose "Searching for emails with subject New Empoyee finished"
      write-output "Searching for emails with subject New Empoyee finished" | timestamp >> $LogFile

          write-output "Parsing Email Body..." | timestamp >> $LogFile 
          Write-Verbose "Parsing Email Body..."

           $allowed_senders = @("user1@example.com", "user2@example.com")
          foreach($result in $searchResults){
            $sender = $result.Sender.Address
              if ($array -notcontains $allowed_senders){
                 Write-Verbose "$sender is not allowed"
              }
              else{
                Write-Verbose "$sender is allowed"
              }

           }
```

user3@example.com is not in array so i expect following output

**Expected output:**

user3@example.com is not allowed

user1@example.com is allowed

user2@example.com is allowed

**Actual output:**

user1@example.com is not allowed

user2@example.com is not allowed

user3@example.com is not allowed

Comment: What does the result of `$sender` from this line `$sender = $result.Sender.Address` look like?  When I mock up my own $searchResults with this, your code works as expected.  `$searchResults = [pscustomobject]@{Sender=@{Address="sam@aol.com"}},[pscustomobject]@{Sender=@{Address="jim@yahoo.com"}},[pscustomobject]@{Sender=@{Address="user1@example.com"}}
`

Comment: `$sender` returns  sender for each email, that's OK

Comment: I mean you need to run your code and see what `$sender` actually contains  when you run your code.  I mocked up the expected results and your code **does** work.  So the problem is that your expected results are different from the actual results.

Answer (score 0):

Figured it out:

i made a typo, i compared non-existing `@array` variable

```
 $TargetFolderSearch = new-object Microsoft.Exchange.WebServices.Data.SearchFilter+IsEqualTo([Microsoft.Exchange.WebServices.Data.FolderSchema]::Displayname,"done") #for each folder in mailbox define search
      $TargetFolder = $MailboxRoot.FindFolders($TargetFolderSearch,$fvFolderView)
      Write-Verbose "Searching for emails with subject New Empoyee finished"
      write-output "Searching for emails with subject New Empoyee finished" | timestamp >> $LogFile

          write-output "Parsing Email Body..." | timestamp >> $LogFile 
          Write-Verbose "Parsing Email Body..."

          $array = @("user1@example.com", "user2@example.com")
          foreach($result in $searchResults){
              $sender = $result.Sender.Address
              if($array -notcontains $sender){
                 Write-Verbose "Not Allowed:$sender"
              }  
              else{
                 Write-Verbose "Allowed:$sender"
              }

           }
```

Output:

user3@example.com is not allowed

user1@example.com is allowed

user2@example.com is allowed

Comment: Try to edit this and add a description of what the problem was, and why it was a problem.  That way more people will benefit from this contribution.